# Populate dropdown field, Gravity forms

Tags: php, gravityforms

I'm using gravity forms with Gravitywiz nested forms. I have a parent form with two child forms in it. I need to populate a dropdown of the second child form based on the user's inputs in the first child form. The issue is the second form dropdown will not be automatically updated, and I need to refresh the page to see new entries.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @Misunderstood there is no code, I just used gravitywiz nested forms plugin.

Comment: Oh?  You have a PHP script that has no code?   I never could understand the concept of gravity.  Or wizardry.   Show the HTML form and any relevant PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the Gravity Wiz folks:

"You can use Populate Anything and the Temporary Parent Entry ID for this.

Here's a video demo of how to set it up and how it would work. https://www.loom.com/share/dff30eec9a174f20ba120ab11280b132

Here's a link to the snippet: https://github.com/gravitywiz/snippet-library/blob/master/gp-nested-forms/gpnf-populate-parent-entry-id.php"

Comment: Could you explain a lit bit more? To clarify the situation consider we have form A as a parent form and forms B and C as nested forms in form A. We need populate fields of Form C based on entries on Form B.

Comment: Sure...I should have asked if you also own Populate Anything from Gravity Wiz as well as nested forms (if you don't, this plugin will solve your issue).  If so, you can just paste the snippet above inside your functions.php.  Then, watch the video and it will show you exactly how to set it up.  

The parent form can have a hidden field that gets populated by a unique id.   You can then add a hidden field into your nested form that grabs that id through a merge tag.

Populate Anything can then grab any data from form B and put it into form C because they share this unique ID.